1.d4 and the Bc8
Can White choose a variant/move order such that there is no good way for
Black to solve the standard problem of the Bc8 in d4 openings and the
dude has to stay put for a while? (Doesn't mean Black has a bad game!)
For example, I read a short article about the Slav exchange variation
and if I understood correctly, Black better play e6 sometime, leaving
the Bc8 on d7.


Can White choose a variant/move order such that there is no good way for Black to solve the standard problem of the Bc8 in d4 openings and the dude has to stay put for a while?

No, not while the Queen's Indian exists.

Perhaps I should have restricted it to 1.d4 d5, but then, I play Queens and Nimzoindian all the time myself and generally avoid d5...
